# SoapUI: Extract Response Value from an Array and Pass Along to Next Request

Tags: arrays, json, rest, soapui

I'm hoping you all can help me once again!

I figured out how to extract a value from a REST response in a simple scenario and pass that value along to a preceding test step, however, now I'm stumped on how to extract a value from an array within a REST response (shown below) to use in a preceding test step.

More specifically, I'm attempting to extract one of the "id" values within answerChoices.

**Response Payload:**

```
(GET) localhost/ws/portal/survey/question/${Create UX Survey Question#ResponseAsXml#//*:id}   

{
       "id": 589,
       "isEnabled": true,
       "type": "RADIO",
       "wording": "SoapUI Test UX Survey Question",
       "answerChoices":    [
                {
             "id": 1546,
             "order": 4,
             "text": "Choice4"
          },
                {
             "id": 1543,
             "order": 2,
             "text": "Choice2"
          },
                {
             "id": 1544,
             "order": 3,
             "text": "Choice3"
          },
                {
             "id": 1545,
             "order": 1,
             "text": "Choice1"
          }
       ]
    }
```

I'm then trying to pass along one of the answerChoices:id to the questionChoiceId value in the next request (shown below).

```
(POST) localhost/ws/portal/survey/alert

{
  "questionChoiceId" : ${},
  "restaurantId" : ${Create New Restaurant#ResponseAsXml#//*:id},
  "alertProfileId" : ${#Project#emailAlertProfileId}
}
```

I just cannot figure it out, I've tried declaring the namespace in the property transfer and that thing just confuses me. Any direction you could point me in would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! So, I wanted to make sure I posted the answer in case anyone else ran into the same problem!

I just wrote a groovy script and did the following:

1. I created two project custom properties (`negativeSurveyAnswer` and `positiveSurveyAnswer`)
2. Add a Groovy Test Step and added the following code:

   ```
   def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
   def questionResponse = context.expand('${Get UX Survey Question Details by questionId#ResponseAsXml}')
   def idVals = questionResponse.split("<id>", -1)
   def Choice1Id = idVals[1].split("</id>", -1)[0]
   def Choice4Id = idVals[2].split("</id>", -1)[0]
   def prop2 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getProperty("positiveSurveyAnswer")
   prop2.setValue(Choice1Id)
   def prop3 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getProperty("negativeSurveyAnswer")
   prop3.setValue(Choice4Id)
   ```
3. With that obtaining the value and transferring it to the Project's properties, the next test step is then:

   ```
    {
     "questionChoiceId" : ${#Project#negativeSurveyAnswer},
     "restaurantId" : ${Create New Restaurant#ResponseAsXml#//*:id},
     "alertProfileId" : ${#Project#emailAlertProfileId}
    }
   ```

Hope this helps others!